# C# Evaluate multiple Xpaths against an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am writing a C# program where I would like to store a series of XPath statements as strings and evaluate them against an XMLDocument (or some other C# XML structure if there's a better one for this purpose) and store the resulting values in a dictionary / object.

My challenge is that my XPaths are not being able to be evaluated.

As a very simplified example, suppose this is my XML:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <child1 Id="Id1" Name="Name1" />
        <child2 Id="Id2" Name="Name2" />
    </a>
</root>
```

and, for example, one of my XPaths is:

```
//a/*[@Id='Id1']/name()
```

(Get the name of `a`'s child element with the `Id` attribute = "Id1")

The simplified version of the code I'm trying to write to do this would be:

```
var xpath = @"//a/*[@Id='Id1']/name()";
var xml = @"<root><a><child1 Id='Id1' Name='Name1' /><child2 Id='Id2' Name='Name2' /></a></root>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

string ChildName = (string)navigator.Evaluate(xpath);
```

but I am getting the error that my XPath has an invalid token - Which I'm assuming the be the `name()` portion.

Is there any way to accomplish this using direct XPath statements rather than traversing the tree?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need to rearrange your XPath if I'm understanding you correctly.  Try this:

```
name(//a/*[@Id='Id1'])
```

Comment: That works! *thank you*!!!
The bigger question is if the idea of using the XmlDocument and Navigator would be the right way to go. Do you have any thoughts if this is the right solution in that case?

Comment: @JohnBustos Using XmlDocument and the navigator is a fine way to go as long as you plan to only be evaluating XPath statements like this.  I normally recommend LINQ to XML for most .NET XML purposes (you can execute XPath with LINQ to XML as well using the `XPathSelectElements`  method).  If you anticipate doing a lot more XML manipulation, I recommend switching to that.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml liinq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication68
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<root>" +
                            "<a>" +
                                "<child1 Id=\"Id1\" Name=\"Name1\" />" +
                                "<child2 Id=\"Id2\" Name=\"Name2\" />" +
                            "</a>" +
                        "</root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("child"))
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id"), y => (string)y.Attribute("Name"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require coding for each value - I was looking for a generic solution such as storing text XPaths. Do you have any ideas for that? Thanks for the code, otherwise, though.

Comment: I can't give answer without more sample data.  I tried to make as generic as possible but don't know what you mean by "each value".